# Take average of segments of NSArray

Tags: ios, algorithm, nsarray, key-value-observing

I have an NSArray of 100 numbers. I would like to create an NSArray of 5 numbers. The first number in the second array is the average of the first 20 numbers in the first array. The second number is the average of the second set of 20 numbers in the first array. And so on.

I'm curious to hear people's ideas for an efficient algorithm.

One idea I had was to do a for-loop on each set of 20 numbers, creating a temp NSArray of 20 numbers. Then perform a KVO average operation and add to the final NSArray.

Note: I always award THE answer to someone, and I'm not shy to up vote your answers. I encourage many answers. Thanks!

Comment: I entirely miss the point of using KVO here....

Comment: It's simple -- write code.  Any "fancy" scheme you might come up with using KVO or whatever is guaranteed to be slower and more obscure.  Unless this is an entry into an obscure code contest or some such, just write the code!

Comment: @Till, maddy just explained to me that KVO is not the same as key-value coding. Now I understand your comment. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is simple and efficient:

```
NSArray *numbers = ... // array of 100 numbers
NSMutableArray *averages = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    float total = 0.0;
    int base = i * 20;
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        float num = [numbers[base + j] floatValue];
        total += num;
    }

    float avg = total / 20.0f;
    [averages addObject:@(avg)];
}

NSLog(@"Averages = %@", averages);
```

Comment: When it comes to efficiency, one may gain a little by omitting the multiplication by 20 within the inner loop. Not hard to figure how to do that...

Comment: Another point, you are using a double value to divide, change the notation to 20.0f to spare another implicit typecast.

Comment: @Zaph The `@(avg)` is shorthand for `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:avg]`.

Comment: Will it make sense to move primitive vars declaration out of the loop as well ?

Comment: `base = i * 20` - why multiplying where you may just add 20 with the same effect ?

Comment: @maddy, sorry, I was not thinking correctly about the `@(avg)`, you are correct. (just finished a two Bloody Mary brunch!)

Comment: @Zaph Huh? Yes, I calculate the average and store it in a variable. Then I need to store the variable (`avg`) in the array. Since you can't store a `float` in an array, you need to wrap the `float` primitive in an `NSNumber`. That's what `@(avg)` does - it wraps the variable `avg` in an `NSNumber` object. It's not some magic for calculating an average.

Comment: Guys, this is an iOS app for calculating 5 averages of 20 numbers each. There's no point in shaving off a couple of CPU instructions. Premature optimization is the bane of software development.

Comment: @maddy Indeed the execution time is not important as I stated in my answer. And as I commented, I knew you could do better--which you did! :-)

Comment: "640 k ought to be enough for anyone" :(

Comment: @rmaddy yes, you are entirely right. Optimising this the way I suggested does not really cut it... Somehow the attribute "efficient" in your answer created a stampede in my brain :D

Comment: @maddy, I did not know about @(avg) and I've never used brackets to reference NSArrays (though I come from c). I learned a lot from this post. Namaste.

Comment: @eddieios That's all newer syntax from modern Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the values in each 20 number section, divide by 20 and put in the appropriate output array location. It is one pass through the array, Big O(n), what more could you ask for? The time to compute this is minuscule.

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this...

```
NSArray *_array = // with the 100 numbers... (I used NSNumber object for each number)

NSMutableArray *_averages = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) [_averages addObject:@([[[_array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(i * 20, 20)] valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.floatValue"] floatValue])];
```

the `_averages` will contain 5 values with the averages of the five different sections of the 100 numbers.

**UPDATED:**

*this part is just for eyes with extra curiosity.*

if you tries to avoid the `NSObjects` and the double `for` loops, you could achieve a really fast algorithm, and of course when you go lower levels, you can improve the current speed as well, the question is: *does it really need?*

```
NSInteger _segments = 1000; // it means 20.000 numbers;
Float64 _numbers[(_segments * 20)]; // fill this array as you'd like.

Float64 _averages[_segments];

for (int i = 0; i < _segments; i++) {
    NSInteger _offset = (_segments<<4)+4;
    _averages[i] = (_numbers[_offset] + _numbers[_offset+1] + _numbers[_offset+2] + _numbers[_offset+3] + _numbers[_offset+4] + _numbers[_offset+5] + _numbers[_offset+6] + _numbers[_offset+7] + _numbers[_offset+8] + _numbers[_offset+9] + _numbers[_offset+10] + _numbers[_offset+11] + _numbers[_offset+12] + _numbers[_offset+13] + _numbers[_offset+14] + _numbers[_offset+15] + _numbers[_offset+16] + _numbers[_offset+17] + _numbers[_offset+18] + _numbers[_offset+19]) / 20.f;
}
```

it is 10 times faster than the solution with `double` for loops and `NSObject` classes.

(un)fortunately, it is not even the ugliest solution, but there is no question it is fast as hell, **I won't recommend it** except the speed *really* matter because that kind of solutions can provide really good efficiency.

Comment: @eddieios That isn't KVO (key-value observing), it's key-value coding.

Comment: FYI - I profiled this solution against the one in my answer. This code on average took 50 times longer to execute as my solution! Of course this solution was plenty fast enough if you only have 100 numbers and you aren't doing the calculation more than a few times.

Comment: @maddy, you just taught me 3 things that make me a better programmer. thanks. I also appreciate you taking the time to profile the code. I really like your answers. Pls continue to follow and answer my questions, and I'll be sure to vote up your answers. Thanks again.

Comment: @rmaddy, and if you go lower level, you could get much faster algorithm. there is no pure miracle here.

Comment: @holex I agree completely. This demonstrates that the more layers of abstraction are added, the slower things get. BTW - the 10x speed increase you show is not just from removing one loop. Most of it is from using C-arrays and only native types.

Comment: @rmaddy, yes, you are right, I forgot this half of sentence, but I've corrected the mistake.